# Разместить много картинок на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть **очень много** картинок, скажем, 300 тысяч. Доступ к ним идёт через ссылку. Например: test.ru/1.png. Нужно разместить их на сайте с плагинацией. Как сделать это **быстро** или **автоматически**?

Comment: Почти идеальный вопрос

Comment: Я бы сказал этот чемпионат уже имеет своего лидера!

Comment: тупо 300 тыс на одной странице? или с пагинацией?

Comment: доступ к картинке идёт через ссылку https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/300000/5.0

Comment: если кому надо там `419852`

Comment: +1 за слово *плагинация*, завтра где-нибудь употреблю

Comment: @Igor слово? или просто? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// делаем плагинацию
var imgPerPage = 30;
var imgCount = 300;//419852;
var pagesCount = Math.floor(imgCount/imgPerPage);
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
for(var i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
  var li = $('<li></li>');
  li.text(i + 1);
  li.attr('data-page', i);
  ul.append(li);
}
$('nav').append(ul);

// вывод изображений выбранной страницы
function showPage(pageNum) {
  var div = $('<div></div>');
  div.addClass('content');
  for(var i = 0; i < imgPerPage; i++) {
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/' + (pageNum*imgPerPage + i) + '/5.0');
    div.append(img);
  }
  $('.content').replaceWith(div);
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('li[data-page='+pageNum+']').addClass('active');
}

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
  showPage(+$(this).attr('data-page'));
});
showPage(0);
```

```css
li {
text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
li.active {
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать таблицу MySQL (например), куда внести за раз все названия картинок, через`for ($i = 0; i < 419852; i++) {
 $name = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/".$i."/5.0";
и дальше INSERT INTO .....
}`
ну а дальше делай пагинацию или бесконечный скроллинг.

Answer (score 0):

Разместите картинки по несколько штук на странице с пагинацией.

Если разместить сразу все картинки на одной странице, - эту страницу будет крайне затруднительно отобразить в обычном браузере.

Comment: Размещать 300 тысяч картинок очень трудно и долго. Есть ли способ сделать это автоматически или побыстрее?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703618/get-all-photos-from-folder-and-paginate-with-php